# SQL Server Hosted on Lightsail Unavailable remotely

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu-20.04, amazon-lightsail

I have a SQL Server - Developer edition - hosted on an Ubuntu 20.04 Lightsail instance in AWS. I have a static IP configured, and I have my ports opened up on 1041 to allow traffic to the server. I am able to SSH into the server remotely, and I can see that the 1041 port is open - however, any time I try to connect to the server through SSMS, I'm unable to actually connect to it, with the error

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TC Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 258)

I'm able to run commands using `/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost,[myPort] -U [myUsr] -P [myPwd] -Q "[myQuery]"`, so I know the server is up and running, and responsive.

I've validated that the server is listening on the SQL Server port by calling `netstat -tunlp`, and seeing that the port is in the `LISTEN` state.

[image: netstat command output]

I've validated that I have no additional Firewall running, so the only thing that should be blocking is the Lightsail Networking. I decided to go for broke, and opened up the server to all TCP traffic - which still got me nowhere.

I've checked to see that remote connections are allowed (they are) - but I have a feeling this is where my issue lies. I read that the command to allow remote connections is `EXEC sp_configure 'remote access', 1 ;`  - I ran this, and rebooted and still nothing. Then I found out that that command isn't necessarily related to allowing remote connections TO the server, and it instead allows remote connections FROM the server.

Is there any other options/tools that I'm missing that I can use to allow remote connections to the SQL Server?

**Edit 1 - Updating ipaddress in config**

On the advice of @AlwaysLearning, I updated my `mssql.conf` file to explicitly list `0.0.0.0` as the ipaddress of the sql server.

[image]

When I did this, I restarted the mssql server, and it now crashes constantly. I removed the 0.0.0.0 address, but it looks like that was able to force mssql to start up listening under 0.0.0.0?

[image]

However, it is still unable to connect remotely. I noticed that when I run `tcpdump -nn -i any port 1041`, I DO see connections to it, but I DON'T see my attempts from my external connection to it. It looks like I'm listening correctly now, but I don't actually get any traffic to the server?

Comment: What address(es) do you have SQL Server configured to listen on? `127.0.0.1:1433` will only be accessible from within the Lightsail instance. If you need it to be accessible from outside the Lightsail instance it needs to be listening on `0.0.0.0:1433`. Please edit your question to include the relevant lines output from `netstat -tunlp`.

Comment: Edited the question to include a screenshot. It looks like that seems to be my issue - I'm listening only on `127.0.0.1:1041` (I updated the port from 1433 to 1041, when I was running this to test it on a home server port 1433 was blocked by my ISP. 

I'm going to look around quick, but if you see this before I reply back, can you tell me how to update it to listen on `0.0.0.0.1041`?

Comment: Have you seen how to adjust network settings using [the mssql-conf tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-configure-mssql-conf#network) or the /var/opt/mssql/mssql.conf file? Most likely network.ipaddress is configured to use 127.0.0.1 so you'd probably want `sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf set network.ipaddress 0.0.0.0`

Comment: @AlwaysLearning updated my question with some specifics - yes, I tried that, and at first it would constantly kill my sql-server service. After removing it, it looks like the server IS listening on 0.0.0.0, but I still can't seem to get connected to it.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - I found the problem. Because I was basing this off of a SQL Server I'm hosting in-home, I was using all of the same values, for the port, the name, everything.

I had a setting in my firewall to forward all traffic on 1041 and 1433 to my in-home server. Which is turned off. 

The answer you posted related to using 0.0.0.0 ended up being necessary as well, as it wouldn't have been listening externally.